# TFS is saying I have a file with status 'lock/edit' and I cannot undo it

Tags: tfs, redgate

In Team Explorer it says I have a file with the status of 'lock,edit' and the undo option is not enabled so I am not sure how to unlock this file.

I am the user who it is reporting that has the lock,edit but I can't undo it.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

You may have multiple workspace. Go to Source Control Explorer -- Workspace, to check whether you have multiple workspace. The change may exist in other workspace. You need to select correct workspace and undo the changes.

[image]

Another way is using TFS powertools. If you install TFS Powertools, you'll see `Find by Status` option by right click the locked file and select `Find`:

[image]

Click `Find by Status` -- `Find`, you 'll see the locked files list. Then right click the files and select `Undo`, the file would be released.

[image]